# Who's your daddy python program

Tags: python

---

I have been having trouble trying to delete an element or pair from my dictionary. It is supposed to delete both the father and the son when you type in the son's name, but it always produces this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jam7733\Desktop\whos ur daddy.py", line 23, in <module>
    daddy()
  File "C:\Users\jam7733\Desktop\whos ur daddy.py", line 20, in daddy
    if del_son in fathers:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

---

here is the code i have:

```
def daddy():
    fathers = {'johnny':'john Dupuis','alex':'jordan belfort','henry':'daniel plainview','mike':'brian cranston','max':'fred man','benny':'nick flick','billy':'robert kardashian'}
    choice = raw_input("do you want to: a)add a father-son pair,b)delete a pair, c)replace a pair,d)look up father-son pair, or e)look for grandfather")
    if choice == 'd':
        name = raw_input("what is the first name of the child? ")
        if name in fathers:
            print name,"is the child of",fathers[name]
        else:
            print "sorry, we do not have this name listed, please try again."
            daddy()
    if choice == "a":
        new_dad = raw_input("what is the name of the new dad?")
        new_son = raw_input("what is the name of the son?")
        fathers[new_dad]=new_son
    if choice == "b":
        print"Here are the names of the fathers that you can delete: "
        print fathers
        del_son = raw_input("what father/son pair do you want to delete?(type first name of son").split(" ")
        if del_son in fathers:
            del fathers[del_son]

daddy()
```

Comment: `del_son` is a list and it cannot be hashed, that is pretty much the beginning and end of the story. You should also use a while True loop instead of having  the function call itself

Comment: `del_son` is no the son. It is a list containing the father and the son. Lists can't be dictionary keys (they are not hashable because they are mutable), so asking if `del_son` is in `fathers` is an error. Ask if `del_son[1]` is in `fathers`. (PS: and give your variables better names to make it harder to make a mistake like this.)

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments by @kindall and @PadraicCunningham, `del_son` is a list:

```
del_son = raw_input("what father/son pair do you want to delete?(type first name of son").split(" ")
```

because here you split its name with a space. Given your code I believe this is a mistake, or there's something you don't understand when you wrote that line.

In python you cannot use a `list` as the key of a `dict`, because a `dict` need all its keys to be non-mutable, in order to ensure that a given key is unique. And in python, `list`s and `dict`s are mutable. That means that when you do:

```
i = 1
i = 2
```

`i` is only a reference to the `int` object instanced with the value `1`. When you assign `2` to `i`, the former instance with value `1` is being forgotten about, and will be collected by the garbage collector. But when you do:

```
l = []
l.append(1)
l.append(2)
```

then you've made a reference from `l` to a `list` object, which you modified to contain two values: `1` and `2`. So now, imagine that you want to index a value with a `list` in a dict, and you do:

```
d = {}
l1 = [3,1]
l2 = [3,4]
d[l1] = 'foo'
d[l2] = 'bar'
```

naively, there's no reason why that wouldn't work and be:

```
{[1,4]: 'foo', [3,4]: 'bar'}
```

but then what if you do:

```
l1.remove(1)
l1.append(4)
```

Then how could the `dict` still work, as the `dict` would then become:

```
{[3,4]: 'foo', [3,4]: 'bar'}
```

Hopefully, you got the `tuple` type which is non-mutable and hashable:

```
d = {(3,1): 'foo', (3,4): 'bar}
```

So you might simply want to not `.split()` it. You might want to `strip()` it (which will remove any leading and trailing whitespace character).

So here you go:

```
del_son = raw_input("what father/son pair do you want to delete?(type first name of son").strip()
if del_son in fathers.keys():
    del fathers[del_son]
```

> my two cents: to make it slightly more explicit, you'd better use `del_son in fathers.keys()`. It's actually the same as what you wrote, simply for readability it's easier, as `del_son in fathers` is misleading (which one could read as: *"is the coder removing a son from the list of fathers? WTH?"*, whereas adding the `.keys()` will read *"Ah! The coder is removing a father from a son→father mapping! Makes sense!"*)

HTH

Comment: Not that it will matter in this case too much but  `if del_son in fathers` is  `O(1)` vs `O(n)` dict.keys()

Comment: oh, you're right. But in this case so much more elegant ☺

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary cannot have a key of type list because the keys MUST be immutable. You can, however, use another immutable type (like a tuple), but that's peripheral to the larger issue. The problem is that you split the name of the son when there is no need to.

```
del_son = raw_input("what father/son pair do you want to delete?(type first name of son").split(" ")
```

This is always going to return a list. When you type:

```
del fathers[del_son]
```

it indexes the fathers dict with a key of a list, which is not allowed. Simply remove the `.split(" ")` after the raw_input and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

For the `del_son` input, you're assigning the result of `raw_input("...").split(" ")`. That **`split()`** returns a list. So `del_son` becomes a list, which can't be used for dictionary keys.

What you want, in this case, is just the first result of the split, so `raw_input("...").split(" ")[0]`:

```
del_son = raw_input("what father/son pair ...").split(" ")[0]
```

That's the first item in the returned list (index 0). Then `del_son` is just the first element, and a string.

If that `raw_input...split...[0]` seems too long, you can leave that line as how you have it now and change the next bit to:

```
if del_son[0] in fathers:
    del fathers[del_son[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing yourself with regard to your index, thereby confusing your dict into a list, since it is now mutable. Looking for a list in a dict, which a list cannot be hashed!